# Tabbed application - how to hide tabbar

Tags: ios

Total noob question, I've searched all the posts but can't understand how to do this.
Created an app using the 'Tabbed Application' template with 3 view controllers, but I am not using a navigation controller. trying to hide the tabbar on the first screen when a button is pushed. All the solutions I have seen use hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES, but this apparentley only works when the view is used in conjunction with a navigation Controller?
Is there some way of accomplishing this only from a view controller in a tabbed application?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can hide tabBar using this code

```
self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden =YES;
```

Comment: Actually, that only works on any view controllers but the first one. Any idea why? Thanks

Comment: its work on first VC. are you sure, in which method you are putting is called?

Comment: Yes, it hits a breakpoint when the button is pushed. I'm completely new to IOS, so not sure if it is because the tabBarController is defined in the first VC (.h) like this: property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *tabBarController; and @synthesize tabBarController (.m). Not sure how this works, I changed the name of the tabBarController as  above to tabBarController1 and the code self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden=YES still works when called from the second VC. Totally confused.

Comment: OK, I got it to work by changing the name of the tabBarController from tabBarController to tabBarController1 in the first VC. So the code self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden=YES isn't referring to the synthesized property 'tabBarController1' - really confused being a noob, but thanks.

Comment: yes, if you are changing name of your default tabbar than you have to mansion name accordingly.